# Fingerprint scanner in Android

Tags: javascript, android, fingerprint, android-fingerprint-api

Android phones use Capacitive and Ultrasonic fingerprint scanners for phone and application locks.
But where these fingerprint data are getting stored is it within the phone or in Cloud and is it possible to extract the fingerprint template data seperatly so that i can push it in my database. 
Android phone can be anything which has fingerprint scanner in the power button.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use the raw data of scanned fingerprint from the mobile's fingerprint scanner. They are stored in the hardware memory and not accessible for extraction and storage. You can only use the fingerprint scanner to authenticate the user with previously stored fingerprint data.

If you need to extract the fingerprint data then you have to use external scanner devices.